# aggregate / count rows grouped by geography (or geometry)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, geospatial, geography

I have a table such as:

```
Create Table SalesTable
( StuffID int identity not null,
  County geography not null,
  SaleAmount decimal(12,8) not null,
  SaleTime datetime not null )
```

It has a recording of every sale with amount, time, and a geography of the county that the sale happened in.

I want to run a query like this:

```
Select sum(SaleAmount), County from SalesTable group by County
```

But if I try to do that, I get:

```
The type "geography" is not comparable. It cannot be used in the GROUP BY clause.
```

But I'd like to know how many sales happened per county. Annoyingly, if I had the counties abbreviated (SDC,LAC,SIC, etc) then I could group them because it would simply be a varchar. But then I use the geography datatype for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function to work with geography type as char

try this

```
Select sum(SaleAmount), County.STAsText() from SalesTable 
group by County.STAsText()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a slightly different structure:

```
create table dbo.County (
  CountyID int identity not null
    constraint [PK_County] primary key clustered (CountyID),
  Name varchar(200) not null,
  Abbreviation varchar(10) not null,
  geo geography not null
);
Create Table SalesTable
( 
  StuffID int identity not null,
  CountyID int not null
     constraint FK_Sales_County foreign key (CountyID)
     references dbo.County (CountyID),
  SaleAmount decimal(12,8) not null,
  SaleTime datetime not null 
);
```

From there, your aggregate looks something like:

```
Select c.Abbreviation, sum(SaleAmount) 
from SalesTable as s
join dbo.County as c
   on s.CountyID = c.CountyID
group by c.Abbreviation;
```

If you really need the geography column in the aggregate, you're a sub-query or a common table expression away:

```
with s as (
    Select c.CountyID, c.Abbreviation, 
        sum(s.SaleAmount) as [TotalSalesAmount]
    from SalesTable as s
    join dbo.County as c
        on s.CountyID = c.CountyID
    group by c.Abbreviation
)
select s.Abbreviation, s.geo, s.TotalSalesAmount
from s
join dbo.County as c
    on s.CountyID = s.CountyID;
```